# Не приходят данные в FireBase

Tags: android, firebase

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseUser currentperson;

private EditText etEmail, etPass;
private Button btnLogin, btnRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    currentperson = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in

            } else {
                // User is signed out

            }

        }
    };
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPass = findViewById(R.id.etPass);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(etEmail.getText().toString(), etPass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                        ref.child(currentperson.getUid());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Регистрация успешна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Регистрация провалена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public void registration(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                ref.child(currentperson.getUid());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Регистрация успешна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Регистрация провалена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Вот вы выложили кусок кода, и что дальше?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы записать данные в Firebase нужно выполнить команду setValue

```
   ref.child(currentperson.getUid()).setValue(something);
```

Вот вам [ссылка](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) для освоения материала, плюс немного процитирую.

> ```
> private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
>    User user = new User(name, email);
>
>    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user); 
> }
> ```